# What are definite integrals that use functions in one or both of its limits?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I've seen these types of questions before, but I think I missed a formal explanation of them. I have a solution to the question in front of me, so my question is not related to what the answer is - but what is the name for this type of problem? I don't quite understand why we're given these kinds of problems other than just because...

Find and simplify the derivative of $\displaystyle\int_{2/x}^{1}\frac{t^{3}}{1+t^{5}}\ dt$

\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_{2/x}^{1}\frac{t^{3}}{1+t^{5}}\ dt\\
&=-\int_1^{2/x}\frac{t^{3}}{1+t^{5}}\ dt\\
f'(x)&=\frac{(2/x)^3}{1+(2/x)^5}\cdot \left(-\frac{2}{x^2}\right)\\
&=\frac{16}{x^5+32}
\end{align}

I'm trying to prepare for my final exam on Wednesday and I'd like to get a bit more background on this type of question so I can better understand what I'm doing if I am asked.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but what you're using is the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: @GitGud I know what the FTC is... and I realize that it is being used in this process... but I'm curious about the type of problem where you're given a definite integral with variables in one or both of its limits.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're looking for. Hopefully someone else will.

Comment: Check out Liebnitz rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(t)$ be any integrable function and define $g(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt$. Then, by the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus), $g(x)=F(b(x))-F(a(x))$ where $F(x)$ is a function with $F'(t)=f(t)$. Now apply the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule):
$$g'(x)=F'(b(x))\cdot b'(x)-F'(a(x))\cdot a'(x)=f(b(x))\cdot b'(x)-f(a(x))\cdot a'(x)$$
In your case, $b(x)=1$, so $b'(x)=0$ and $a(x)=2/x$ hence $a'(x)=-2/x^2$